# QT Creator - iostream no such file or directory (Mac)

Tags: macos, qt

I have program in QT Creator3.4.2 (Macbook El Capitan).
The line `#include <iostream>` was under lined and says no such file or directory.

How to resolve this issue ?

Comment: #include <iostream> ? Which C++ compiler are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because I just updated the XCODE and haven't accepted the terms and condition. 
I just accepted the T&A and restarted, its works fine now...